# Wifi does not work ubuntu 16.04 resently upgraded

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade

I just upgraded my ubuntu to 16.04, and after a couple of days of working fine suddenly it stopped funtcioning. There is only one network available in the network list, and it's not mine.There are usally a lot of the as I live in a city. My mobile wifi neither has effect. The conection editor does not seem to give me any solution. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205 download the script form their, run it and paste the info in pastebin.com

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Please write the output of:

```
rfkill list
```

If your wlan0 is hard blocked, unblock it with fn+f2 button (or some other f button, which enables/disables wifi).